# Stripe payment charge

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-6, laravel-cashier

I want to charge payment using paymentMethod as a source but it does not charge, how do I get token as the source using payment method? I tried to charge using

```php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_**************');
\Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => $menuPrice*100,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => $user->stripe_id,
    'source' => 'pm_*************'
]);
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to include your key and customer `source` in your post.

Comment: ok, but i  want to know how can i get ```card_***********``` or ```tok_**********``` to use as source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charges are the older way of doing this; the new way is Payment Intents (with Payment Methods).  You can find out about the differences here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration

Comment: thank you, i found a way from this documentation :)